# Let S be a subset of $\mathbb{C}$. If $z,w \in S$, define $z ∼ w$ if and only if there is a path from z to w. Show that ∼ is an equivalence relation.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, equivalence-relations, path-connected

Let S be a subset of $\mathbb{C}$. If $z,w \in S$, define $z ∼ w$ if and only if there is a path from z to w. Show that ∼ is an equivalence relation.

Definition of path: A path in $\mathbb{C}$ is a continuous function $\gamma:[a,b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $\gamma(a)$ = initial point, $\gamma(b) =$ end point.

From my understanding, I need to show 3 components: reflective, symmetric, and transitive.

For Reflective, I have:
Suppose $z_1 = x_1 +iy_1 \in \mathbb{C},$ then
$x_1 +iy_1 - (x_1 +iy_1) = 0$ is a path

Symmetric:
Suppose $z_1=x_1 +iy_1 \in \mathbb{C}$ and $w_1 = x_2+i+y_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ and $z_1Rz_2$, then there is a path from z to w. Since $\gamma:[x_2,y_2]\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$, there is a path from w to z.

Transitive:
Suppose $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$ and z~w and w~y, then there is a path from z to w and from w to $y=x_3+iy_3$. Thus $\gamma:[x_1,y_3]\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ so there is a path from z to y.

Am I going about these the right way?

Comment: What is your definition of a path from a complex number to another complex number?

Comment: Definition of path: A path in $\mathbb{C}$ is a continuous function $\gamma:[a,b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $\gamma(a)$ = initial point, $\gamma(b) =$ end point.

Comment: You are misunderstanding your definition of a path. $\gamma: [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a path from $\gamma(a)$ to $\gamma(b)$. It seems like you are thinking that $a, b$ are the initial point and end point. That's not right, and $a, b$ are numbers in $\mathbb{R}$. $\gamma(a)$ and $\gamma(b)$ are the initial point and end point in $\mathbb{C}$. Also $[z, y]$ doesn't make sense since they are complex numbers.

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: @DuduBob yes i understood the definition. I changed $[z,y]$ to $[x_1,y_3],$ does the other components look correct?

Comment: @pop You need to give your path explicitly. For example, do you know for sure that $y_3 > x_1$? If not, the interval still doesn't make sense. Perhaps my answer below can help you.

Comment: Could you explain why I cannot use an arbitrary path, instead of [0,1]?

Comment: @pop You can use an arbitrary path. [0, 1] just makes the notations easier. The point is, you get to decide what [a, b] is, and what the actual function $\gamma$ is. In your proof, you didn't define what $\gamma$ actually is.

Comment: You're confusing the initial point of the domain, $a$, with the real part of the start of the path. That is, if $\gamma\colon [a, b] \to \mathbb{C}$ and $\gamma(a) = x_1 + i y_1$, then in general it's *not* the case that $a = x_1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, $[a, b]$ is an interval in $\mathbb{R}$. For reflexivity, let $x \in S$ and let $\gamma:[0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be the constant map given by $\gamma(t) = x$ for all $t \in [0,1]$. Then $\gamma$ is clearly continuous, and $\gamma(0) = \gamma(1) = x$. So that's a path from $x$ to $x$.

Now suppose there is a path $\gamma : [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ from $x$ to $y$, i.e. $\gamma(a) = x$ and $\gamma(b) = y$. Then let $\tilde{\gamma} : [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be defined by
$$\tilde{\gamma}(t) = \gamma(b+a-t)$$
Then $\tilde{\gamma}$ is continuous because $\gamma$ is, and $\tilde{\gamma}(a) = \gamma(b+a-a) = \gamma(b) = y$, and $\tilde{\gamma}(b) = \gamma(b+a-b) = \gamma(a) = x$. So $\tilde{\gamma}$ is a path from $y$ to $x$.

For transitivity, suppose $\gamma:[0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a path from $x$ to $y$ and $\theta: [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a path from $y$ to $z$. Define $\delta: [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by
$$\delta(t) = \gamma(2t), 0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\delta(t) = \theta(2t-1), \frac{1}{2} < t \leq 1 $$
Note that $\delta$ is continuous at $t = \frac{1}{2}$. This is a path from $x$ to $z$.

Comment: For symmetry, do we have $\tilde{\gamma}$ is a path from y to x, or is it the same thing?

Comment: @pop Ah that's a typo. Thanks I will correct it.